# Adobe Reader 9.0 memory leak while loading-unloading PDF files every one second indefinitely

Tags: memory-leaks, adobe-reader

I have c++ written MFC based application that has PDF object viewer as a part of the implementation. A whole thing works just fine with Adobe Reader 8.0. Once I switched to Adobe Reader 9.0 as a default PDF reader, I keep experiencing small memory leak that forces my application to crash within a half an hour of continuous loading-unloading different PDF files. Any ideas what might cause this memory leak and is there any cure besides replacing Adobe Reader 9.0 with anything else? 
(Works fine with Foxit PDF reader as well, by the way..)

Answer (score 0):

One possible cure is spawning off a separate process to handle the component, and restart it every once in a while.

This tip if actually quite often useful in situations you have to deal with buggy third party components, see http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/04/2402028.aspx for an example.